# MongoDB Giveaway Timer

Tags: mongodb, function, timer, discord.js, document

I have a **MongoDB** schema created. I am trying to make it so the number in the document will decrease every second. I already have the interval part done, but **the issue is when I try using the "updateMany" MongoDB function, it seems to be doubling how many seconds decreased.
NOTE: I want it to remove 1000 milliseconds from the timer for each document that is in the schema.**

Code:

```
setInterval(async () => {
      
      const schema = await giveaway.findOne({ GuildID: interaction.guildId })
      
      if (schema) {

        await giveaway.updateMany(
          {
            $inc: {
              timer: -1000
            }
          }
        )

          if (schema.timer === 0) {
            console.log("Giveaway Done!");
            return schema.deleteOne({ GuildID: interaction.guildId });
          }
      }
    }, 1 * 1000);
```

Comment: If the connection to mongodb hasn't already been established by sending a command, the first run may take longer than 1 second, so you effectively get multiples running at the same time at first.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Waitt, nevermind. I get what you are saying, that was really obvious but thank you!